# Maven classpath trouble with Maven-selenium plugin

Tags: maven, selenium

We're using Maven 3.0.3 and using the Maven Selenium plugin to attempt to start a Selenium server.  We have this dependency in our pom ...

```
            <dependency> 
                    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId> 
                    <version>2.19.0</version> 
                    <classifier>noexe</classifier> 
            </dependency>
```

Then in the pre-integration phase we try and start Selenium server ...

```
    <build> 
            ... 
            <plugins> 
                    ... 
                    <plugin> 
                            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> 
                            <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                            <version>1.1</version> 
                            <executions> 
                                    <execution> 
                                            <id>start</id> 
                                            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase> 
                                            <goals> 
                                                    <goal>start-server</goal> 
                                            </goals> 
                                            <configuration> 
                                                    <background>true</background> 
                                                    <logOutput>true</logOutput> 
                                            </configuration> 
                                    </execution> 
                            </executions> 
                    </plugin>
```

But the server fails to start with the error ...

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/server/SeleniumServer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main"
```

I have verified that the dependency above contains the missing class.  How else can I troubleshoot this classpath problem or can you tell what is wrong with the setup I've listed here?

Thanks, - Dave

Comment: plain guess: Did you write `mvn clean install` into console after adding dependency? See here http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html